# visualize the windsor castle objects

Tags: list, memory-leaks, castle-windsor, castle, instances

Is it possible to list all the objects that the container is holding on to? And the count of instances for each object type. This could be seen as a monitoring tool to catch "memory leaks".
A graph would be even nicer.

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like a [performance counter](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Performance-Counters.ashx)?